# How to change numbers to roman numerals in align environment

Tags: numbering, align, environments

What is the way to change the way the align environment numbers the equations?
[image]

Say I want to change the (1) to a (I) or a (A)

Comment: That is not really something align does, but all the eqn giving envs. Is it only this particular one or do you want all eqn numbers like that? And BTW welcome

Comment: Related: [How do I number equations with roman numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63138/5764)

Comment: Really I was just looking to change one particular one, but the answer given helped.
And thanks btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` from `mathtools`. Here are a few samples:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{Alph}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}]()
\newtagform{roman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}]()
\newtagform{scroman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\scshape\roman{equation}}][]

\begin{document}

\usetagform{Alph}
\begin{equation} 
a = b + c 
\end{equation}
\usetagform{roman}
\begin{equation}
d = e + f
\end{equation}

\usetagform{default}
\begin{equation}
x = y + z
\end{equation}

\usetagform{scroman}
\begin{equation}
u = v + w
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]