# Enumerate a list of equations

Tags: equations, enumerate

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\itemsep -0.2em
\item \begin{equation*}
    e^z =  \sum_{n=0} z^n / n!
\end{equation*}
\item \begin{equation*}
    \sin z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n+1}/ (2n+1)!
\end{equation*}
\item \begin{equation*}
    \cos z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n}/ 2n! \\
    \text{which converges } \forall \ z \in \C 
\end{equation*}
\item \begin{equation*}
    \log_e (1 - z) = - \sum_{n=1} z^n/n
\end{equation*}
\item \begin{equation*}
    (1 - z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0} z^n \\
    \text{which converges for } |z| < 1 
\end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can I get the enumeration numbers (i, ii, etc) on the same line as the equations?

[image: Img1]

Comment: Why do you use `equation*` if you want the behavior of `equation`?

Comment: I want the enumeration to do the labeling on the left, `equation` won't do that. Further, I don't want the equations _labeled_ as such, but enumerated.

Comment: It will do it! LaTeX is very flexible. Btw: If you use `enumitem` never mess with `\itemsep` manually.

Comment: @AthenaWidget And now please admit that `equation` will do it :)

Comment: potential duplicate: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394)

Comment: @TeXnician Correct. `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything in your questions, which couldn't be done using `equation`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\newcounter{dummy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   normalequation
\end{equation}

\bgroup
    \leqnomode
    \setcounter{dummy}{\theequation}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}%

    \begin{equation}
        e^z =  \sum_{n=0} z^n / n!
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \sin z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n+1}/ (2n+1)!
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \cos z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n}/ 2n! \\
        \text{which converges } \forall \ z \in \C 
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \log_e (1 - z) = - \sum_{n=1} z^n/n
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        (1 - z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0} z^n \\
        \text{which converges for } |z| < 1 
    \end{equation}

    \setcounter{equation}{\thedummy}
\egroup

\bgroup
    \leqnomode
    \setcounter{dummy}{\theequation}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}%

    \begin{equation}
        e^z =  \sum_{n=0} z^n / n!
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \sin z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n+1}/ (2n+1)!
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \cos z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n}/ 2n! \\
        \text{which converges } \forall \ z \in \C 
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \log_e (1 - z) = - \sum_{n=1} z^n/n
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        (1 - z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0} z^n \\
        \text{which converges for } |z| < 1 
    \end{equation}

    \setcounter{equation}{\thedummy}
\egroup

\begin{equation}
   normal equation
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`\leqnomode` is borrowed from [Tag placing with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212085/36296)

Comment: Probably the spacing would be better with `gather` or `align`.

Comment: @Bernard Probably. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: No, I think I'll add a ‘real’ enumerate answer instead. You can update your answer if you wish. Perhaps you might add details on how to maintain the current equation counter.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the enumerate environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), leftmargin=*, itemsep=0.4ex, before={\everymath{\displaystyle}}]%
  \item $ e^z = \sum_{n=0} z^n / n! $ \label{eq-1}
  \item $ \sin z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n+1}/ (2n+1)! $\label{eq-2}
  \item $ \begin{aligned}[t]
        & \cos z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n}/ 2n!\\
        & \text{which converges $ \forall \ z \in \C $} \label{eq-3}
  \end{aligned}
  $
  \item $ \log_e (1 - z) = - \sum_{n=1} z^n/n $ \label{eq-4}
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t] & (1 - z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0} z^n ,\\
        &\text{which converges for $ |z| < 1 $} \end{aligned}$ \label{eq-5}
\end{enumerate}
 It is easy to prove eq. \ref{eq-3}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on the [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)'s comment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[leqno, fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ mathtools }

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\newtagform{Alph}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}]()
\newtagform{roman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}]()
\newtagform{scroman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\scshape\roman{equation}}]
[]

\begin{document}

\usetagform{roman}
\begin{align}
   &e^z =  \sum_{n=0} z^n / n! \\
   &\sin z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n+1}/ (2n+1)! \\
   &\cos z = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n z^{2n}/ 2n! \text{   which converges } 
   \forall \ z \in \C  \\
   &\log_e (1 - z) = - \sum_{n=1} z^n/n \\
   &(1 - z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0} z^n  \text{   which converges for } |z| < 1 
\end{align}

%\setcounter{equation}{0}
\end{document}
```

References:

[Switch between leqno and reqno options (of amsmath) in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document)

[How to change numbers to roman numerals in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330075/how-to-change-numbers-to-roman-numerals-in-align-environment/330081#330081)

[image: Equations]

Comment: Something occurred to me, what if I wanted the equations enumerated *and* labeled. I think @samcarter has the better answer.